# How to shuffle an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

The code below works for a normal array but not with an array with object does anybody knows how to do this?

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

const result = shuffle(array);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: can you elaborate more what kind of structure of array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: What do you mean by "array with object" ?

Comment: This code is agnostic to the content of the array. Replace all numbers to objects - { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, etc... and you can see it.

Comment: In my experience, this works except for this one case:  an associative array where every element is an array of objects.  If I pass one of those array elements (which is itself an array) to this function, then the array is not shuffled.  However, if you modify the code to make a copy of the array and then shuffle that and return it, that will work.  You must use a legitimate array copy method like:  newArray =  [...array],  in other words, newArray = array won't work.

Answer (score 54):

Try sorting like this snippet:

```js
console.log( [
    { some: 1 },
    { some: 2 },
    { some: 3 },
    { some: 4 },
    { some: 5 },
    { some: 6 },
    { some: 7 },
  ]
  .sort( () => Math.random() - 0.5) );
```

In reponse to Martin Omanders comment: here's a shuffle method according to the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://medium.com/@oldwestaction/randomness-is-hard-e085decbcbb2)

```js
const result = document.querySelector("pre");
for (let i=0; i<20; i+=1) {
  result.textContent += 
    JSON.stringify(shuffleFisherYates([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])) + '\n';
}

function shuffleFisherYates(array) {
  let i = array.length;
  while (i--) {
    const ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [array[i], array[ri]] = [array[ri], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Which may be condensed to a one liner (**note**: this one liner will not compile in the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler) with level advanced):

```js
const shuffle = array => 
  [...Array(array.length)]
    .map((el, i) => Math.floor(Math.random() * i))
    .reduce( (a, rv, i) => ([a[i], a[rv]] = [a[rv], a[i]]) && a, array);
const result = document.querySelector("pre");
for (let i=0; i<100; i+=1)
  result.textContent +=
   JSON.stringify(shuffle([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])) + '\n';
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Others have pointed out that this solution (while cute and good enough for some uses) isn't very random: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/455313

Comment: The OP is already implementing Fisher-Yates shuffle in his question. So you're saying to do what he's already doing?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more example based on lodash **[_.shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#shuffle)**.

```js
const array = [
    { some: 1 },
    { some: 2 },
    { some: 3 },
    { some: 4 },
    { some: 5 },
    { some: 6 },
    { some: 7 },
  ];
console.log(_.shuffle(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to shuffle a collection of element nodes (in the DOM), convert it to an array first:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('someid');
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(wrapper.children);
```

Shuffling a HTMLCollection object (as returned by `children`) directly doesn't work even if you can iterate the collection with a for loop. This stumbled me for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but @Koolinc's updated function for the Fisher-Yates algorithm has an error in the while loop as it is written. It creates an infinite loop because the while loop never ends. Here is the updated function:

```
function shuffleFisherYates(array) {
  let i = array.length;
  while (i > 0) {
    const ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    i--;
    [array[i], array[ri]] = [array[ri], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```