# How can I shuffle a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, random, shuffle

I am trying to randomize the order of my array in my Angular6 project. I have no idea how to do it and ended up trying to sort the array with the `Math.random()` function... (didn't work XD)

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
    <div style="background: darkcyan; width: 600px; height: 600px; margin: auto">
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let card of cards">
      <div id="{{card.id}}" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': card.color}" style=" width: 100px; height: 125px; margin: 5px"></div>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button (click)="shuffle()">Shuffle Cards</button>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-memory-game',
  templateUrl: './memory-game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./memory-game.component.css']
})
export class MemoryGameComponent implements OnInit {
  cards = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cards = [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'color': 'red'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'color': 'green'
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'color': 'blue'
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'color': 'yellow'
        }
    ];
      this.shuffle();
  }

  public shuffle() {
      this.cards.sort(Math.random);
  }
}
```

I don't know if there is an easy solution, but I really hope someone is able to help me out..

Thanks

Comment: `Math.random` always returns a positive number, so the result will not be random. Refer to @Shan-Desai's answer to solve the issue (by substraction 0.5 from `Math.random` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53066842/1423259

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to do something like:

```
this.cards.sort((a,b) => 0.5 - Math.random());
```

[based on some previous answers on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array#2450976)

Or do something like this:

```
 this.cards.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
```

Based on this [SE Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555273/how-to-shuffle-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: This answer doesn't shuffle uniformly. For better ways, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array#2450976

Comment: the fisher yates algorithm would be better for this

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution you could take would be to create a function to generate a random int and use it in your `Array.prototype.sort` function callback:

```js
var cards = [{
    'id': 1,
    'color': 'red'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'color': 'green'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'color': 'blue'
  },
  {
    'id': 4,
    'color': 'yellow'
  }
];

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

cards.sort(function(a, b) {
  return getRandomInt(cards.length) - getRandomInt(cards.length);
});

console.log(cards);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this shuffle function.

```
function shuffle(arrParam: any[]): any[]{
    let arr = arrParam.slice(),
        length = arr.length,
        temp,
        i;

    while(length){
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * length--);

        temp = arr[length];
        arr[length] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

It is a pure function and can be used on any array.
It will create a new shuffled array preserving the original one.

If you want to make it work in your template so it sorts `this.cards`, you can make the component method `shuffle()` that mutate `this.cards`:

```
public shuffle(): any[]{
    let arr = this.cards.slice(),
        length = arr.length,
        temp,
        i;

    while(length){
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * length--);

        temp = arr[length];
        arr[length] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }

    this.cards = arr;
}
```

EDIT: I checked @wannadream link he provided in a comment and it looks like my `shuffle` function above is "The de-facto unbiased shuffle algorithm is the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle". I must have written it using Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm as a reference.