# display the question to div using innerhtml from array by clicking next button

Tags: javascript

I am making a flashcard which has bunch of question and I store them using array. I did random the questions but sometimes the questions is appear more than one. I'm about to show the question one by one by clicking the next button. Also, if the questions is finished, it should be stop to random the questions.

```js
var btnNext = document.getElementById("next");
words = [{
    question: "HTML stands for",
    answer: "HyperText Markup Language"
  },
  {
    question: "What is a href?",
    answer: "Link location attribute"
  },
  {
    question: "What is extensions used to save HTML pages?",
    answer: ".html"
  }
]

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tempWords = [];

  if (tempWords.length === 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      tempWords.push(words[i]);

    }
  }

  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempWords.length);
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=tempWords[index]?.question;
});
```

```html
<div id="question">
  <h3>Questions</h3>
</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Each time the control reaches the `click` event, `tempWords` is set as an empty array. Thus, every time the `for` loop executes and populates the full array. I've edited the code in the question above - so, it displays the question (previously it was just displaying the index, instead). You need to design a mechanism to track which questions were already shown - to avoid showing them again.

Comment: FWIW: [FIsher-Yates reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/13658816).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing what you want which i can think of

- Shuffle the array and print questions one by one till the end of the array
- Print random questions and removing them from the array

### Shuffling the array

You can shuffle the array using differents methods and i've followed [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555388/11260991) to do it which look the simplest

You can then remove each time the first question using the js `shift` method which remove the first element from an array and returns it

```js
var btnNext = document.getElementById("next");
words = [{
    question: "HTML stands for",
    answer: "HyperText Markup Language"
  },
  {
    question: "What is a href?",
    answer: "Link location attribute"
  },
  {
    question: "What is extensions used to save HTML pages?",
    answer: ".html"
  }
]

const randomWords = words.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (randomWords.length > 0) {
    
    const question = randomWords.shift()
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question.question;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="question">
  <h3>Questions</h3>
</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

### Printing random question

The second way works with the js `splice` function which remove elements from an array and return the removed elements [(documentation here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

#### Printing question

To print question you can then access the function using the `slice` method :

```js
const question = words.splice(index, 1)[0] // taking the first element because slice return an array
```

and then printing it using InnerHTML as you did

```js
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question.question;
```

```js
var btnNext = document.getElementById("next");
words = [{
    question: "HTML stands for",
    answer: "HyperText Markup Language"
  },
  {
    question: "What is a href?",
    answer: "Link location attribute"
  },
  {
    question: "What is extensions used to save HTML pages?",
    answer: ".html"
  }
]

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (words.length > 0) {
    var tempWords = [];

    if (tempWords.length === 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        tempWords.push(i);

      }
    }

    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempWords.length);
    const question = words.splice(index, 1)[0]
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question.question;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="question">
  <h3>Questions</h3>
</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is: Random the array at first.
So your code (JS part) should be like this:

```js
var btnNext = document.getElementById("next"),
tempwords = [{
    question: "HTML stands for",
    answer: "HyperText Markup Language"
  },
  {
    question: "What is a href?",
    answer: "Link location attribute"
  },
  {
    question: "What is extensions used to save HTML pages?",
    answer: ".html"
  }
],
words = [],
num = 0;
while (tempWords.length !== 0) {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempWords.length);
  words.push(tempWords[index]);
  tempWords.splice(index, 1);
}
delete tempWords;

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (num < words.length) {
    let indexItems = words[num++];
  }
  // More code....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By putting track on index whether they are used previously or not.

```
  const btn = document.getElementById("next");
  var indexArray = [];
  btn.onclick = function getNewQuestion() {
    let tempWords = [
      "What is the capital of India?",
      'What is mean by "Lo siento"?',
      'What is mean by "mesa"?',
      'What is mean by "Para"?',
      "What is mean by 'Bonito'?",
    ];
    let index = getValidIndex(indexArray, tempWords.length);
    console.log(tempWords[index]);
  };

  // function to get valid non-repeative index
  function getValidIndex(indexArray, lengthOfTempWords) {
    let indexs = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthOfTempWords));
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
      if (indexs == indexArray[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      if (indexArray.length === lengthOfTempWords) {
        return -1;
      }
      return getValidIndex(indexArray, lengthOfTempWords);
    } else {
      indexArray.push(indexs);
      return indexs;
    }
  }
```