# Randomize order of <div>s or <li>s with pure JS on page load

Tags: javascript, random

I saw multiple answers to randomize the order of `<div>` (or `<li>`s or whatever) using jQuery, but how do I do this using pure javascript?

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
  <li>Answer 1</li>
  <li>Answer 2</li>
  <li>Answer 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
  <li>Answer 1</li>
  <li>Answer 2</li>
  <li>Answer 3</li>
  <li>Answer 4</li>
  <li>Answer 5</li>
  <li>Answer 6</li>
</ul>
<script>
(function() {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper")
  const children = Array.from(wrapper.children)

  for(i = children.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [children[ri], children[i]] = [children[i], children[ri]]
  }
  children.forEach(node => wrapper.appendChild(node))
})()
</script>
```

First it takes the children of the wrapper and converts them to an Array using `Array.from`. Then it's using [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://medium.com/@oldwestaction/randomness-is-hard-e085decbcbb2) to shuffle the array and finally we call `forEach` on the array and add each `<li>` again to the wrapper in order of the shuffled array (adding an element will remove it from it's previous position).

Comment: Just to add something, you don't need to remove the element first. The append action moves the node to its new place :)

Answer (score 2):

Randomly shuffle an array of cloned `li` elements and replace original with the new ones:

For the `shuffleFisherYates` function [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555388/58186)

```js
function reOrderListItemsRandomly(ulId) {
  const ul = document.querySelector(`ul#${ulId}`);
  const liElems = ul.querySelectorAll(`li`);

  // create new array with cloned li elements and shuffle it
  const nwLiElems = shuffleFisherYates([...liElems]
    .map(li => li.cloneNode(true)));

  // replace the old li with the corresponding li from the 
  // array of new elements, see also
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith
  [...liElems].forEach( (li, i) => li.replaceWith(nwLiElems[i]) );

  // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555388/58186
  function shuffleFisherYates(array) {
    let i = array.length;
    while (i--) {
      const ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      [array[i], array[ri]] = [array[ri], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }
}

// button handling
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `shuffle`) {
    return reOrderListItemsRandomly(`wrapper`);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
  <li>Answer 1</li>
  <li>Answer 2</li>
  <li>Answer 3</li>
  <li>Answer 4</li>
  <li>Answer 5</li>
  <li>Answer 6</li>
</ul>
<button id="shuffle">shuffle answers</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Fisher-Yates, I've incorporated it into my solution. However, I don't yet see the point of cloning and replacing the `<li>`s.

Comment: Cloning is not really necessary. I would've factored it out later (like you did), if I needed the function.